# Reverse and Concat a List

Tags: elixir

What is the most idiomatic way of concatenating a reversed version of a list to the original list? So:

```elixir
Input:  [1, 2, 3], which is the output of my_func()
Output: [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

One could achieve this in a not very idiomatic way like this:

```elixir
n = my_func() # returns e.g. [1, 2, 3]
n_reversed = Enum.reverse(n)
n_combined = Enum.concat(n, n_reversed)
```

I was thinking about something like this (doesn't work):

```elixir
my_func() |> Enum.concat(Enum.reverse(&(&1)))
```

This solution does work, but doesn't look very idiomatic to me:

```elixir
n |> Enum.reverse() |> (fn enum -> Enum.concat(n, enum) end).()
```

Do you know a idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it would be more idiomatic to use the `++` operator instead of `Enum.concat`.  (Note that `++` requires the arguments to be lists, whereas `Enum.concat` accepts any kind of enumerable.)

```
n_combined = n ++ Enum.reverse(n)
```

Comment: That's much more idiomatic indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If it's something you do frequently and you're trying to avoid writing the variable name twice to keep a pipleline going, you could wrap it up in a function.

```elixir
def reverse_concat(list), do: list ++ Enum.reverse(list)
```

Then something like

```elixir
my_func() |> reverse_concat()
```

produces

```elixir
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: If it’s about not writing the name twice: `[1,2,3] |> List.duplicate(2) |> Enum.reduce(& &1 ++ Enum.reverse(&2))` :)

Comment: This comment solves the problem exactly as asked for. If you put this into an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: If you want to go that far, `[1,2,3] |> (& &1 ++ Enum.reverse(&1)).()` ;-)